# Problem using datetime.now() to schedule events a specific times. It needs to be second accurate but occasionally it skips a second

Tags: python, python-datetime

I'm currently writing Python code that sends a trigger message to another programme (Pure Data), via UDP using socket, at specific times.

Specifically, I want Python to send a string, "Play", to Pure Data on the beginning of every hour and the beginning of every half hour. It needs to be second accurate, so that when the current hour, minute and second line up with when I want, the string is sent.

My code seems to generally work, however, I did notice that occasionally, a second ends up being skipped. This is a big problem for me if the 0 second is skipped at the start of the half hour, because then Python won't send the string to Pure Data.

For an example of what I mean, see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHD8c.png), which shows time output from the code. The time jumps from 16:07:02 to 16:07:04, missing out 16:07:03.

I can increase the time.sleep(1) interval in my while loop to something like time.sleep(.5), so that this is avoided, but then, Python will send two or three strings in a row to PureData, which I also don't want.

I'm wondering how I can make the Python code so that it is always second accurate and never skips a second, like it's currently doing.

Here's the code, for reference.

```
import time
import datetime
import socket

# Start and end hours for PureData playback
startHour = 9
endHour = 18

# Set up UDP connection with PureData
s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 3001
s.connect((host,port))

# Send Test Message to PureData
testMsg = "Python3 Connection Open ;"
s.send(testMsg.encode('utf-8'))
print('Start-Up Message Sent to PureData')
time.sleep(1)
playMsg = "Play ;"

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    day = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()

    #let triggers happen between Monday (0) and Staurday (5), but not Sunday (6)
    if day == 6:
        print(str(now) + " | No Triggers Will be Sent Today.")

    if day >= 0 and day <= 5:
        # If the time is in the correct range
        if now.hour >= startHour and now.hour <= endHour:

            if now.hour == endHour and now.minute == 30 and now.second == 0: # catch trigger 30 mins after end hour
                print(str(now) + " | Triggers Have End for Today.")

            elif (now.minute == 30 or now.minute == 00) and now.second == 00:
                s.send(playMsg.encode('utf-8')) # Send play message to PureData
                print(str(now) + " | Trigger Sent.")

            elif now.minute < 30:
                print(str(now) + " | Next Trigger Will be Sent at " + str(now.hour) + ":30:00.")

            elif now.minute > 30:
                print(str(now) + " | Next Trigger Will be Sent at " + str(now.hour + 1) + ":00:00.")

        # If the time is great than the end hour and less than midnight
        if now.hour > endHour and now.hour < 0:
            print(str(now) + " | Triggers Have Ended for Today.")

        # If the time is less than the start time
        if now.hour < startHour and now.hour >= 0:
            print(str(now) + " | Triggers will begin at " + str(startHour) + ":00:00")
```

Comment: Reason is that the code in the loop needs also time to execute which adds  to the sleep. Solution: before sleep retrieve current time in seconds and calculate the remaining sleep time.

Comment: @MichaelButscher do you mean giving time.sleep something like like this: sleepInterval = 1 - (now.microsecond  / 1000000)

Comment: Not exactly but basically. The modulo operator `%` is also handy to calculate the next time until to sleep. Also use the helpful answer of zmccord.

Comment: @MichaelButscher using the method I mentioned above seems to produce stable results for what I need actually. I'm just checking the output regularly at the moment to make sure. I probably should consider zmccord's method, especially if I want to get more accurate than a second...

Answer (score 1):

Code that depends on a particular relationship to time in order to be correct is difficult to write correctly, and is subtle. For example, suppose it just so happens your system is heavily loaded by another process and swap thrashes for a bit right as the clock passes the hour, and your code doesn't happen to run during that period at all?

You are keeping track of what triggers you have already sent implicitly, by reasoning about the current system time. This is fraught. If you instead keep track of that information explicitly, your code will be more robust.

Instead of checking whether this loop is the first second past the hour, you could keep track of when the loop last ran. If the hour has changed between the last time the loop ran and now, then the clock has struck the hour, regardless of whether you caught it on the exact second that it did so.

Alternatively, you could keep track of when you last sent a certain trigger, and re-send it if it's been more than a certain time since that trigger was last sent. This would be appropriate if you don't really care that it happens on the hour, but you do care that it happens regularly. It would also be easier to finely adjust the trigger frequency if you think about the problem this way.

Comment: Thank you for this @zmccord. So, for my use case, if I'm following you right, you're suggesting triggering a loop that counts out 30 minute intervals? And that this would be would start at the beginning of the hour and then just run / reset / run continuously until I specify it to no longer operate?

Comment: I'd actually really appreciate an example of what you're referring to, if possible. I'm not a full-time coder or anything, so my knowledge is sometimes limited when it comes to implementing solutions.